# Ionic 4 / 5 Routing / How to “skipLocationChange” in a “Tab App”?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes, tabs

I’ve converted my app to a PWA and i’ve noticed that, when I change the route, the url changes too:
for example if my app runs on localhost:8100 when i click “home” the url becomes localhost:81/home

I’ve fixed this using this.router.navigate([’/home’], {skipLocationChange: true}); and my url bar now only shows localhost:8100

The problem is with the Tabs: if i click on the tabs, even if I use skipLocationChange, the url changes to localhost:81/tabs/somepage

There is a way from preventing the url bar to changes or to show the full path when I click on the tabs?
My goal is to keep the url bar always with “localhost:8100” even if the path changes.

thank you!

Comment: This is not a common error or not something related to ionic or angular, its related to something in your code, so maybe you need to post your tabs router plus the places where you add the routing from or file router, plus instead of navigate you could use navigateByUrl('/....');

Comment: thank you Mostafa, but tab's buttons doesn't have a proper "router navigator", with ionic 4 / 5 you have <ion-tabs> and <ion-tab> and when you click on the tab button it automatically changes the routing destination. That's why everything works when clicked with navigate or navigateByUrl and doesnt work when I click directly on the tab's buttons.